# Extending classes - type support

Tags: typescript

I have abstract class let's say `Conditions`. It is than extended by `BoolCondtions`, `TextConditions` and so on...

I have interface that looks like this:
`export interface ConditionModel {type: string; class: Conditions}`

But when I create object using that model typescript complains about that `BoolConditions` is imcompatibile with `Conditions`:

```
export const myConditions: ConditionModel[] = {
  {type: 'bool', class: BoolConditions},
  {type: 'text', class: TextConditions},
}
```

Typescript does not support extending classes?

Comment: is tha wroked foryou ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this , means you need to create of object, right now you are assigning type directly - that is the reason its giving error.

```
export const myConditions: ConditionModel[] = {
  {type: 'bool', class: new BoolConditions()},
  {type: 'text', class: new TextConditions{}},
}
```

or

```
export const myConditions: ConditionModel[] = {
  {type: 'bool', class: {} as BoolConditions },
  {type: 'text', class: {} as TextConditions},
}
```